# SurrealDB - How to change table name in SurrealQL?

Tags: database, surrealdb

I have a table called "**Computers**".

I want to change it to "**computer**".

**There must be no data loss while changing the name.**

How can I change it? How to change table name in SurrealQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a direct method to change the table name without data loss in SurrealQL. However, you can accomplish your objective `(change the table name from "Computers" to "computer")` using the following technique:

1. Create a new table named "computer" with the same structure.
2. Migrate data using `INSERT INTO computer SELECT * FROM Computers;`.
3. Verify data consistency.
4. Update any references to the old table name.
5. Drop the old "Computers" table.

***Remember to back up your data before making changes.***

Comment: It would be nice if surrealdb team just add a simple RENAME or an additional UPDATE command to achieve this in one line. Thanks a lot.